# python code needed to be break down and or made simple

Tags: python

Can you please break this code down for me to understand?

```
print hash(tuple([int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]))
```

I want to understand how this can be made in more than one line.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the inside:

```
raw_input().split()
```

will [take user input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), return it as a string, and [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) it on whitespace characters into a list. So if the user enters `'1 2 3'` this would give `['1', '2', '3']`.

```
[int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
```

is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that takes that list of characters, and makes a new list with each character represented as an [integer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int). So with our previous example user input, this list comprehension would return `[1, 2, 3]`.

`tuple(...)` will [return a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) with all the elements of the list comprehension, giving us `(1, 2, 3)`.

Finally, `hash()` will return the [hash value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash) of the object.

Here is one way you could spread this over multiple lines (done in an interactive IPython interpreter:

```
In [1]: inp = raw_input('Enter your values')
Enter your values1 2 3

In [2]: inp
Out[2]: '1 2 3'

In [3]: vals = [int(i) for i in inp.split()]

In [4]: vals
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3]

In [5]: input_hash = hash(tuple(vals))

In [6]: input_hash
Out[6]: 2528502973977326415

In [7]: hash(tuple([int(i) for i in raw_input().split()])) == input_hash
1 2 3
Out[7]: True
```

The last few lines show that the `hash()` is the same, regardless of whether you do everything in one line, or over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of this code

```
a = raw_input().split() ## Taking a string of nums as input
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(int(i))
b = tuple(b)
print hash(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

why would you do that in the first place? list comprehensions are way to go.
anyways here's how you can do it:

*(posting as an answer because I couldn't format code snippet in comments section)*

```
temp = []
for i in raw_input().split():
    temp.append(int(i))
print hash(tuple(temp))
```